# bash pid output showing two numbers

Tags: linux, bash

I am running the following bash script sorry, new to bash programming here!) and I am struggling to understand the output of a script I have written, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROCID=$(pgrep firefox)
echo "the process is $PROCID"
```

When the run the above `.sh` script, I get:

```
the process is 2185
9341
```

I am deeply troubled by this 9341 number - what is this?
I tried googling it, but couldnt find an explanation to this.

Thanks and sorry if this is a 101 question.

Comment: Is it `pid` of bash shell/terminal running,kindly check the output of `ps` command!

Comment: can you paste the output of `ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep -e 2185 -e 9341`

Comment: What did you call your script?  If you called it `check-for-firefox`, it will show up too.  Try `pgrep sh`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
DESCRIPTION
       pgrep looks through the currently running processes 
       and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout.  
       All the criteria have to match.
```

You probably have more than one process of firefox running ,You can verify using

```
ps aux | grep -e 2185 -e 9341
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that you have multiple firefox processes running on your machine.
Verify with `ps aux|grep firefox`, you should get the same process ids.